# 'TypeError: a float is required' error when applying numpy fft on conjugate of numpy ndarray

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, fft

I have a numpy array `X`. I need an fft on the conjugate of that array. The following cod:

```
      print(type(X.conjugate))
      print(type(M))

      Xf = np.fft.fft(X.conjugate, M).conjugate
```

produces:

> < class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>
> < class 'numpy.float64'>

With the error massage:

> line 189, in fft
>       a = asarray(a).astype(complex, copy=False)
>   TypeError: a float is required

In python3.5/site-packages/numpy/fft/fftpack.py .

when printing `print(type(X))` I get

> < class 'numpy.ndarray'>

- What does the float error refers to?
- How do I resolve this?
- Is it leagal to pass the conjugate? Is it also considered an ndarray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `X.conjugate` method, have you tried using [`numpy.conj`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.conj.html)?

Since it's an array, I don't think the `X.conjugate` method is returning a complex array.